# Is the city in which Fruits Basket is set ever identified?

Tags: fruits-basket

*Fruits Basket* appears to be set in a real Japanese city.
Is it ever explicitly stated which one?
If not, is it possible to deduce which one, or at least which part of Japan it's supposed to be?

(I'm more interested in the answer vis-a-vis the manga, but if there's a clue in the anime, that would be fine too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not state their location in the anime or the manga. It is however commonly believed that Fruits Basket takes place in a more rural area of Tokyo Japan.

Comment: By "more rural area of Tokyo Japan", you mean a rural or semirural area *near* the Tokyo metropolis, yes?

Comment: Yes, Zack that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

So, after having done some work and trying to find some landmarks, i believe that Fruits Basket (2019) takes place somewhere near Tamagawadai Park half between Yokohama and just at the edge of Tokyo. The skyline when they are on the roof looking at the city and the specific blue bridge in season 1 episode 23 give the best references as to where they are, from what we currently know about the anime. I noticed the bridge since i've been cycling in that specific area before.

Check out the pictures that Yokohama Expat has on his blog. https://reywatjapan.blogspot.com/2015/07/wilderness-in-tokyo.html

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange! This has the potential for becoming a great answer. If it's possible, could you also [edit] to provide image comparisons for the blue bridge from the anime and the real-life? Thanks!

Comment: This [blog](https://astral01.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/18/202037) goes into great detail regarding comparison with real-life places. There is a lot of Den-en-chōfu among other places.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought it looked more like Kyoto personally. Especially with all the mountains so easily accessible. But it could well be Tokyo and the mountains too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently watching the new Fruits Basket s2, ep 5 and they go to this restaurant and a guy orders Chicken Nanban. Chicken Nanban is a famous dish of Miyazaki prefecture, the restaurant called Nao-chan boasting to be the first and best. It's one of my favorite foods I've ever had in Japan so when he said this, immediately I was like "MIYAZAKI".

Comment: Please includ relevant sources/references to support your answer.

Answer (score -4):

My sister believes that Fruits Basket takes place in China due to the fact that it has the Chinese Zodiac. Note: Chinese.  But this is just  a simple guess.